# Android Login and registration using wamp server, phpmyadmin, eclipse, json

Tags: java, eclipse, json, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I am trying to create a login interface following this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etYVqYAhp6w&feature=bf_prev&list=UUnzGVPkz3rZcrLh9jKbKNQw - Parts 1 to 6.

When I run the application on the Android emulator it returns toast message 'Login Unsuccessful' (a declared exception in Main.java file below).

The main.java file connects to the php file - index.php which I save in directory wamp/www/index.php, which then communicates with the 'mobiledb' stored on the wamp server (on my local machine).

A user has been created in the database and I try to login through the emulator which should validate the login details and give toast message 'Success!'.

If anyone could give any help on what could be the issue, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Main.java

```
package com.kibriaali.logintutorial;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    EditText etUser, etPass;
    Button bLogin;

    //Create string variables that will have the input assigned to them
    String username, password;

    //Create a HTTPClient as the form container
    HttpClient httpclient;

    //Use HTTP POST method
    HttpPost httppost;

    //Create an array list for the input data to be sent
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    //Create a HTTP Response and HTTP Entity
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initialise();
    }

    private void initialise() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
        //Now to set an onClickListener
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // This is where we will be working now

        //Create new default HTTPClient
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Create new HTTP POST with URL to php file as parameter
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/wamp/www/index.php"); //92.4.131.132 //127.0.0.1 //10.0.2.2

        //Assign input text to strings
        username = etUser.getText().toString();
        password = etPass.getText().toString();



        //Next block of code needs to be surrounded by try/catch block for it to work
        try {
            //Create new Array List
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

            //place them in an array list
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "username"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "password"));

            //Add array list to http post
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            //assign executed form container to response
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost); //response from the PHP file

            //check status code, need to check status code 200
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== 200){

                //assign response entity to http entity
                entity = response.getEntity();

                //check if entity is not null
                if(entity != null){


                    //Create new input stream with received data assigned
                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                    //Create new JSON Object. assign converted data as parameter.
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                    //assign json responses to local strings
                    String retUser = jsonResponse.getString("user");//mySQL table field
                    String retPass = jsonResponse.getString("pass");

                    //Validate login
                    if(username.equals(retUser)&& password.equals(retPass)){ //Check whether 'retUser' and 'retPass' matches username/password 

                        //Create a new shared preference by getting the preference
                        //Give the shared preference any name you like.
                        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("logindetails", 0);

                        //Edit the Shared Preference
                        SharedPreferences.Editor spedit = sp.edit();

                        //Put the login details as strings
                        spedit.putString("user", username);
                        spedit.putString("pass", password);//May not need to store password

                        //Close the editor
                        spedit.commit();

                        //Display a Toast saying login was a success
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {
                        //Display a Toast saying it failed.

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Login Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }


            }


        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Display toast when there is a connection error
            //Change message to something more friendly
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Unsuccessful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }






    }//END onClick()

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }//END convertStreamToString()

}
```

INDEX.PHP file

```
<?php
//turn off error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);

//Create fields for the database
//server, username, password, database

$dbhost = "localhost"; //92.4.131.132 //127.0.0.1 //10.0.2.2
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbdb = "mobiledb";

//connect to mySQL
$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("connection error");

//Select the database
mysql_select_db($dbdb)or die("database selection error");

//Retrieve the login details via POST
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//Query the table android login
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM androidlogin WHERE user='$username' AND pass='$password'");

//check if there any results returned
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

//If a record was found matching the details entered in the query
if($num == 1){
    //Create a while loop that places the returned data into an array
    while($list=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        //Store the returned data into a variable
        $output = $list;

        //encode the returned data in JSON format
        echo json_encode($output);

    }
    //close the connection
    mysql_close();


}

?>
```

Note: Internet permissions have been enabled in Android manifest file.

Comment: `"http://127.0.0.1/wamp/www/index.php"` u sure this the correct address?

Comment: I have tried a few variations of this url the tutorial suggests 'http://10.0.2.2/wamp/www/index.php' but I've had no luck :(

Comment: i hope you didn't overwrite the index.php in `wamp/www/`. :) You can create a folder `mysite` in `wamp/www/` and put your script there. Access it in your browser through `http://localhost/mysite/index.php` or  `http://youripaddresshere/mysite/index.php`.

Comment: Created 'mysite' folder and accessed from browser, it returned a pink background screen - 404 not found File not found.

Comment: Just replaced 'youripaddresshere' with 'localhost' and it was accessed succesfully from browser

Comment: Here you can find the complete detail code of android,php and sql of login and registration system in android. http://www.startingandroid.com/registration-and-login-with-back-end-php-and-mysql/